# Mapbox .js API Auto Zoom to GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox

I have a simple page with a mapbox-based map using GeoJSON to populate the required LineStrings. I am looking for a way for the extents to be auto-set each time the map is loaded. Currently, I am calculating the max and min lat/longs and setting the view that way, but I still need to define a zoom level when I do that. I've seen some functions relating to setting the bounds, but I can't seem to make that work while still using my GeoJSON. Any suggestions?

```
    <script>
    L.mapbox.accessToken = '[removed]';

    var geojson = [

                {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 2,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [    [-123.116589,49.209164],[-123.117103,49.208972],[...removed for clarity...],[-123.111908,49.284047] ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "10 DOWNTOWN",
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 5,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                }
            },

                {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 2,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [    [-123.134782,49.203239],[-123.135147,49.203328],[-123.135894,49.203637],[-123.136782,49.203951],[-123.138169,49.204423],[-123.138759,49.20457],[-123.139587,49.204862],[-123.140005,49.205046],[-123.140243,49.205186],[-123.140395,49.205325],[-123.140532,49.205506],[-123.140631,49.205792],[-123.140586,49.20707],[-123.140534,49.208535],[-123.140463,49.210515],[-123.140448,49.210886],[-123.140432,49.211372],[-123.140401,49.212256],[-123.14037,49.213145],[-123.140369,49.213145],[-123.14036,49.213735],[-123.140355,49.213998],[-123.140776,49.214006],[-123.140789,49.213746] ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "10 GRANVILLE TO 63RD",
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 5,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                }
            },

                {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 2,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [    [-123.134782,49.203239],[-123.135147,49.203328],[...removed for clarity...],[-123.127194,49.277803],[-123.128135,49.278406] ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "10 TO DAVIE",
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 5,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                }
            },

                {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 2,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [    [-123.134782,49.203239],[-123.135147,49.203328],[...removed for clarity...],[-123.116191,49.281213],[-123.117871,49.280109],[-123.118797,49.280722],[-123.119815,49.281368] ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "10 TO ROBSON",
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 5,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                }
            },

                {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 2,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [    [-123.110919,49.284708],[-123.111908,49.284047],[-123.112864,49.283416],[...removed for clarity...],[-123.116589,49.209164] ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "10 GRANVILLE",
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 2,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                }
            },

                {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 2,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [    [-123.110919,49.284708],[-123.111908,49.284047],[...removed for clarity...],[-123.134852,49.202151] ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "10 TO MARPOLE",
                    "stroke": "#0324a7",
                    "stroke-width": 2,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                }
            }];

    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets');
    map.setView([49.2437385, -123.1258535], 12);



    L.geoJson(geojson, { style: L.mapbox.simplestyle.style }).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L.GeoJSON` inherits the `getBounds` method from `L.FeatureGroup`. You can use it to fetch the bounds of your layer:

> Returns the LatLngBounds of the Feature Group (created from bounds and coordinates of its children).

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-getbounds

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    style: L.mapbox.simplestyle.style
}).addTo(map);

var bounds = geojsonLayer.getBounds();
```

You can use those bounds with the `fitBounds` method of your L.mapbox.map (L.Map) instance:

> Sets a map view that contains the given geographical bounds with the maximum zoom level possible.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Fantastic - makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Here's what ended up working with my code

`var geojsonlayer=L.geoJson(geojson, { style: L.mapbox.simplestyle.style }).addTo(map);

var bounds = geojsonlayer.getBounds();

map.fitBounds(bounds);`